# Removing subarray from array with splice

Tags: javascript, slice, sub-array

I am using splice method to remove a subarray from an array with the following code:

```
    for(let i = 0; i < cid.length; i++)
    {
      if(coinsValue[cid[i][0]] < troco && cid[i][1] > 0)
          available += cid[i][1]
      if(coinsValue[cid[i][0]] > troco)
          cid[i].splice(0)
    }
```

The output is :

```
[ [ 'PENNY', 1.01 ],
  [ 'NICKEL', 2.05 ],
  [ 'DIME', 3.1 ],
  [ 'QUARTER', 4.25 ],
  [ 'ONE', 90 ],
  [ 'FIVE', 55 ],
  [ 'TEN', 20 ],
  [ 'TWENTY', 60 ],
  [] /// removed elements from this array, but not the array itself ]
```

As you can see the elements that fit the condition are removed and I'm still left with an empty array. However I want to remove it completely!

Any help?

Comment: What is your example input data, and what's your expected output?

Comment: it seems like you should use `cid.splice(i, 1)`; `cid[i].splice(0)` delete all elements of subarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing items from a sub array, not from the array itself.

To remove item from the top array you should do like this:

`cid.splice(i, 1)` instead of `cid[i].splice(0)`

```
for(let i = 0; i < cid.length; i++) {
    if (coinsValue[cid[i][0]] < troco && cid[i][1] > 0) {
        available += cid[i][1];
    } else if (coinsValue[cid[i][0]] > troco) {
        cid.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```